# How to invoke javascript function from href for multiple links within a table

Tags: javascript, href, location-href

I have a table that contains a column with multiple filenames. The filenames are actually links with some of them pointing to a URL and some of  them pointing to a local file. I can successfully download a local file and point to a url in a new window when clicked upon independently.

However, when I try to do this dynamically by passing in the filename via the js function within the `href`, I encounter an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`. This does not seem to be a problem when I just call the js function without any parameter, however, then all the links just point to the last filename in column. I can see at the bottom of my browser `javascript:openLink(filename)` with the proper filename, but then the error happens.

[image: table]

This is my code:

```
function searchAjax(){
    var $table = $("#tableGrid").tablesorter(),
            $tbody = $table.children("tbody");
            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'table_results',
                type: 'GET',
                data: $('#filterForm').serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#tableGrid").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                    $.each(data, function(index, result) {
                        function openLink(value){
                            var link = value;
                            if(link.indexOf("http") > -1 ){
                                window.open(link, "_blank");
                            }
                            else{
                                location.href="/projectv1?fileName="+link;
                            }
                        };
                        $tbody.append(
                                "<tr>" +
                                "<td>" + result.regionCode + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + result.nationCode + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + '<a href="javascript:openLink('+result.link+')" target="_blank">link</a></td>"' +
                                "</tr>");

                    });
                        $("#tableGrid").trigger("update");
                }
            });
        };
```

Comment: Could you show us some example "result" data?

Comment: When do you get the error? When you invoke `openLink`? Where is the code for `openLink` function ?

Comment: @Tom, I've added an example table that shows the results

Comment: Sorry, I meant could you show us the actual object? `console.log(result)` should bring it up in your console.

Comment: @laruiss, I receive the error upon clicking on the link so when the openLink function is invoked. The code for the function is above the appending for each row.

Comment: @Tom, when I type it into console, I get this - ReferenceError: result is not definedmessage: "result is not defined"stack: (...)get stack: function () { [native code] }set stack: function () { [native code] }__proto__: Error

Comment: You have to put that line in your code where result is defined  - because it wasn't globally scoped, it won't be available in the console directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change your html appending code like this

```
$tbody.append(
    "<tr>" +
    "<td>" + result.regionCode + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + result.nationCode + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + '<a class="customLink" data-url="'+result.link+'">link</a></td>"' +
    "</tr>");
```

and you can add click event handler to your customLink .

$(this).data('url') retrieves the link data from html element's data attribute .

```
jQuery(document).on(
{    
    click: function(e) 
    {
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        openLink(url);
    }
}
, '.customLink');
```

you should also move your openLink function definition to an outer scope

Comment: When you say "to an outer scope", do you mean the openLink function that I have should be moved outside of the searchAjax function?

Comment: Wow, that was amazing, that solved my dilemma! Thanks very much!

Comment: yes , you cannot call openLink function from outside of searchAjax function